What does $H^m(X)[-m]$ means in the context of derived categories?
I am studying derived categories. I know that for a complex $X$ in $D(A)$ (where A is an abelian category) the shift functor $[n]$ send the complex $X$ to $X[n]$ where $X[n]^i= X^{n+i}$ and $d_{X[n]}^i = (-1)^nd_X^{n+i}$.
Furthermore $H^i$ is the functor which sends a complex $X$ to the object $\frac {\ker d^i}{\operatorname{im} d^{i-1}}$ in A.
I have often seen the notation $H^m(X)[-m]$ but without an explanation: How should the shift functor operate on an Object in A? What does this notation mean?

You identify objects $X$ of $A$ with complexes $X[0]= \dots\rightarrow 0\rightarrow X\rightarrow 0\rightarrow \dots$ so $X[0]^0=X$ and $X[0]^i=0$ otherwise.
